# Django Form Returning Invalid

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to implement a form that has checkbox options for a field, and a user can select multiple checkboxes for that specific field in the form and all the check-marked values should be sent in the POST request.

But `views.py` is saying that the form is invalid when I try to submit the form. The reason it is invalid is this
 `Select a valid choice. [&#39;top&#39;, &#39;mid&#39;] is not one of the available choices.`

I get a similar error when I only select one checkbox.

Here is my partial `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
LEAGUE_ROLES = (
    ('top','Top'),
    ('mid','Mid'),
    ('jungle','Jungle'),
    ('bottom','Bottom/ADC'),
    ('support','Support'),
)
class CreatePosting(models.Model)
    createPostingOpenRoles = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices=LEAGUE_ROLES, default=None)
    def __str__(self):   # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.title
```

Here is my partial `forms.py`

```
class TeamPostingCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CreatePosting
        widgets = {
            'createPostingOpenRoles': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }
        fields = '__all__'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TeamPostingCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is my partial `views.py`

```
def createposting(request):
    UserTeamPostingCreateForm = TeamPostingCreateForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        UserTeamPostingCreateForm = TeamPostingCreateForm(request.POST)
        if UserTeamPostingCreateForm.is_valid():
            logger.error("valid form")
        else:
            #print form error
            logger.error(UserTeamPostingCreateForm.errors)
    variables = { 'form': UserTeamPostingCreateForm }
    return render(request, 'createposting.html', variables)
```

And in my template, I have this for the form field

```
{{ form.createPostingOpenRoles }}
```

Let me know if you need any more code.
I tried researching for the solution but nothing was working for me.

I'd appreciate any help, thank you

UPDATE

So I printed out the choices that `views.py` will render to the template with this

```
    logger.error(UserTeamPostingCreateForm.fields['createPostingOpenRoles'].choices)
```

and I got this output

```
[('top', 'Top'), ('mid', 'Mid'), ('jungle', 'Jungle'), ('bottom', 'Bottom/ADC'), ('support', 'Support')]
```

Then when I submit the form with checkboxes 'Top' and 'Mid' marked I get this an invalid form, because:

```
Select a valid choice. ['top', 'mid'] is not one of the available choices.
```

Comment: You're using an apostrophe and it's getting converted into its HTML character code: `&#39;`. Try enclosing the values in `LEAGUE_ROLES` with double quotes.

Comment: So I replaced the single quotes to double quotes in `LEAGUE_ROLES`, but form still returns invalid for the same reason. I even tried changing `models.CharField` to `models.IntegerField` in `models.py` and changing my values in `LEAGUE_ROLES` to integers, but the form is still invalid because: `Select a valid choice. [&#39;2&#39;, &#39;3&#39;, &#39;4&#39;] is not one of the available choices.`

Comment: What if you made it integers and removed the quotes altogether?

Comment: @wpercy hi, I tried doing that but did not work, the form is still invalid for a similar reason. See my last comment for more details

Comment: Try defining each of your options inside your model class like they suggest in the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices

Comment: I moved `LEAGUE_ROLES` to be inside the model class but still the same issue occurs.

Comment: I've added more information

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're trying to pass a list of two text values into a `CharField`. A list is (for obvious reasons) an invalid choice for a `CharField`. If you want to allow for multiple options, consider using a `JSONField` (postgres only) or perhaps a [`MultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield).

The MultipleChoiceField definition would look something like

```
createPostingOpenRoles = models.MultipleChoiceField(choices=LEAGUE_ROLES)
```

The "empty" value for a MultipleChoiceField is an empty list (`[]`)